# CSS Button overlaps box on mobile

Tags: html, css

I add a blog sign up form to the sidebar of our blog page and styled it with CSS. It looks fine on desktop view, but when you open the page on a mobile phone then the button overlaps the bottom of the page;

https://screentimelabs.com/parenting-hacks/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spRpu.png)

Here's the code that I added to the style sheet;

```
     .sidebar-widget #mc_embed_signup{
     width: 278px;
     height: 211px;
     background: url(https://screentimelabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/bg_logo.png);
     border: solid 1px silver;
     box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 1px silver;
}
    .sidebar-widget #mc_embed_signup h2{
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: "Sans Pro Regular", sans-serif;
    font-size: 26px;
    margin: 4px 0;
}

   .sidebar-widget #mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group{
   font-family: "Sans Pro Regular", sans-serif;
   color: #ffffff;
}
   .sidebar-widget #mc_embed_signup .mc-field-group{
   font-family: "Sans Pro Regular", sans-serif;
   color: #ffffff;
}
   .sidebar-widget #mc_embed_signup input.button{
   color: #FFFFFF;
   border: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
   background-color: #ffc23b;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   margin
}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated, spent hours on this now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change this class like this,

```
.sidebar-widget #mc_embed_signup {
width: 278px;
height: auto;
background: url(https://screentimelabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/bg_logo.png) no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
border: solid 1px silver;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 1px silver;
}
```

Comment: But in this case, The background image will repeated vertically. Oliver B-S please check, If it works for you. O.W. you need to do some style changes for mobile view.

Comment: @Prasad Edited the answer to overcome that issue :)

Comment: @TheDarkKnight thanks so much that makes sense. I have used auto before not sure why I didn't use it this time. Probably gone blind looking at it. Anyway thanks again. Also changed the width to auto so that it fits better on all devices btw.